# Symfony/Doctrine - How do I create a checksum for a table row?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, checksum, data-integrity

the advent of data protection laws led to a myriad of security requirements...
I need to implement an integrity functionality on every table row, preferably through doctrine.

Consider this:

A Table with 3 Columns **A**, **B** and **C**, where **Column C** is a checksum.
When a user creates an entry by providing values for Column A and B, a checksum is generated by appending the values of A and B to a unique, permanent salt and saved to **Column C**.

Also, when a user changes the value of **Column A**, a new Checksum must be generated.

Is there a way to implement that functionality natively with doctrine, or is it only possible with custom Entity-Listeners?

Thank you

Comment: What would this checksum guard against? Presumably if you can modify A or B, you could also modify C, right? Would you expose this checksum to users so that they could note it somewhere and determine that if something changed? If something does change, can you tell what has changed, for instance is there a changelog?

Comment: It's up to you. Can be as simple as defining a `calcCheckSum` method on your entity that sets C and is called in both the constructor and the setter for A. If you go the listener route, might be best to have a `CheckSummable` attribute for entities that mark them to easily filter out in the listener, and `CheckSumSource` and `CheckSumStore` attributes to rely on for generating and storing the sum. See the official DoctrineExtensions project for examples of adding behavior via attributes if you need inspiration

Comment: @Optimum Adding the logic for generating the Checksum inside the Entity-Class will make the salt inaccessible, because the scope is limited to the entity - at least that is my assumption. My goal is an implementation that needs the least amount of code because that checksum will be implemented on every Entity (pls do not make me count them...).
But if Symfony does not offer any built-in solution, a Custom Persister for every entity would probably provide the highest verbosity and performance.

Comment: @ChrisHaas a checksum for a single row is useful, because it provides two level data-integrity. Consider a deployment of your application on the in-house infrastructure of a customer. That customer has database-admins that have access to your database, but not the application source-code. If an admin decides to do some evil stuff directly on the database level, that can be very destructive to your data-integrity. So it is very convenient to have a checksum generated through source-code as a sort of 2-factor-authentification to safe-guard your data from manual changes.

Comment: @Bricklet again, up to you, the option that scales with the least amount of work is best. Packages that add behavioral extensions to doctrine either leverage traits or a listener + attributes. I suggested the methods since you could technically put it in a trait, but after considering it a bit more I think this is one instance where the listener route is actually best. Though you already sound pretty confident.

Comment: @Optimum thank you very much for your input, I will consider the Listener route more and see where it leads me

Comment: I get the general idea of what you are going for along with the reasons, however guarding against theoretical rouge admins with limited admin access is an uphill battle IMHO. Please know I'm not judging in any way, just trying to take a step back a think about it. So will you validate the checksum on every read, too? Otherwise a rogue admin could change something, cause badness, then change it back.

Comment: Another option is a single dedicated checksum table that stores the source table, ID, timestamp and a checksum, no relationships. Every insert/update writes to this table. You could even use the previous checksum in future checksums (similar to a block chain) to give you further data integrity.

Comment: I do agree it is an uphill battle. Safe-guarding against every possible angle of attack will lead to attrition in devs and code-efficiency. Though it provides security that is completely detached from the database management system. And while the actual implementation becomes pretty exhausting the higher your entity-count is, that kind of additional integrity constraint is not a lot of work in itself - in coding and computing power. The only downside is you can not fix in-production issues by directly accessing the database^^

Comment: That Checksum-Table is a good idea. I will look into that, thank you for your suggestion

Comment: "The only downside" - I don't want to belabor the point, but the other downside is that the checksum must be validated on every read, and any read that doesn't validate is a potential vulnerability that could be exploited. You can probably solve that with a listener or trait, but I just want to make sure it is clear that the checksum shouldn't be used in hindsight, it must be front and center always.

Comment: valid point. It is not necessarily a real-time validation but rather just a periodic failsafe check to see if any rows have been changed by malicious users. In my work-env the application usage ends after about 1 month. Reports and whatnot are then generated and it helps to be certain that this report-data is unchanged. Very helpful input though, I will consider it